# secure_file_priv and mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, mariadb

**Question:** How can we avoid errors of the following type with `mysqlimport` when the data file is in the current directory?

> mysqlimport: Error: 13, Can't get stat of
> '/var/lib/mysql/«dbname»/«tablename».txt' (OS errno 2 - No such file
> or directory), when using table: «tablename»

We are using MySQL version `8.0.28`.

---

**Background:**

Our issue started with `LOAD DATA INFILE` giving the following error:

> The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it
> cannot execute this statement

This issue was resolved by following the tip from https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-solve-mysql-server-is-running-with-the-secure-file-priv-error/

Basically we edited the MySQL options file to set `secure‐file‐priv = ""`.
Additionally we ensured that the owner and group of the file is set to `mysql`.

With these changes `LOAD DATA INFILE` is working like a charm.  However, these changes have had no impact on `mysqlimport`.

`mysqlimport` gives the following error:

> mysqlimport: Error: 13, Can't get stat of
> '/var/lib/mysql/«dbname»/«tablename».txt' (OS errno 2 - No such file
> or directory), when using table: «tablename»

Comment: Check if OS account used for mysqlimport execution have privileges in the filesystem for to access this file.

Comment: @Akina the file is in `/tmp` directory and has `777` permission.

Comment: Nevertheless mysqlimport cannot access this file. This is an issue in OS/filesystem permissions, not mysql/mariadb server problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to fix the problem by first enabling LOCAL capability for LOAD DATA

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL local_infile = TRUE;
```

After that we started invoking `mysqlimport` with `--local` option.